# Use realm in a isolated module with domain object and storage object

Tags: android, realm

i have some questions about realm library for android.

Now, i have a app module, that contains all bussines logic, with his custom domain objects like Work, and i have a storage module, this module not know anything about app module, but app module knows interface WorkStorage from storage module. Storage module has owns custom objects used only for persistence, like WorkDB..

Currently i have a translator, where i have a public WorkDB translate(Work); (In app module) method, i pass a work and translates me to WorkDB, and later i send to workStorageImpl.saveWork(WorkDB) (In StorageModule)

I want to start to use Realm, but i see that for create an Realm extend object, like my WorkDB i need to use Realm.createObject() because WorkDB contains a list of other Realm childs objects.

When i use Realm.createObject() i am using storage and persistence logic, and i want to do this in storage module, not in app, but i cant find the way to create a WorkDB pojo (exteding RealmObject) in APP module..

Any idea..?

Answer (score 1):

Christian from Realm here. What you ask for is currently not possible due to how our annotation processor works. Currently all model classes are required to be present in the module they are used. We are however working on a concept called Realm modules, which allow you to share model classes between projects and define them pr. Realm. You can follow progress on that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/938